# aiogram, Бот, ответы на вопросы

Tags: python, aiogram

Как сделать чтобы бот слушал все сообщения, но реагировал на них если: 1)тип сообщения от пользователя будет текстовой тогда бот выдаёт нужную информацию, 2)если пользователь вводит что-то отличное от текста, тогда бот будет выводить ему что-то вроде ошибки, я понял что нужно внести параметрв в @dp.message_handler(content_types=????), сделал, как реагировать только на текст, а что-бы он паралельно реагировал на остальные сообщения, не пойму как, неужели нужно перечислить все типы сообщений в @dp.message_handler?

Comment: А в список вложения делал? `@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'document', 'photo'])`

Comment: в этом то и вопрос, не хочу перечислять все типы сообщений, должен же быть проще способ.

Answer (score 2):

Если поискать в примерах в [репозитории aiogram](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram), то много чего полезного можно найти. Например, частично то, что Вам нужно - [эхо-бот](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-2.x/examples/echo_bot.py):

```py
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    # old style:
    # await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

    await message.answer(message.text)
```

Теперь, Вы можете достать из объекта `Message` тип сообщения, и делать с этой информацией всё, что хотите. Например, в Вашем случае, выглядеть это будет примерно так:

```py
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.ANY)
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    if message.content_type == types.ContentType.TEXT:
        # Тут делайте всё, что нужно, если юзер отправил обычное сообщение
        await message.answer("Вы отправили текст!")
    else:
        # Всё, что не попадает под текст
        await message.answer("Отправьте, пожалуйста, текст!")
```

Ну, или так:

```py
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.ANY)
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    if message.text:
        # Тут делайте всё, что нужно, если юзер отправил обычное сообщение
        await message.answer("Вы отправили текст!")
    else:
        # Всё, что не попадает под текст
        await message.answer("Отправьте, пожалуйста, текст!")
```

Comment: пробовал, не подходит, выдаёт ошибку: AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'type'

Comment: А если проще писать? Пример здесь https://pastebin.com/AK5Uhg0g

Comment: Обновил ответ, спасибо за замечание, так тоже можно сделать

Comment: Не работает, бот реагирует только на текстовое сообщение, если отправить что-то другое, он не отвечает вовсе.

Comment: Может нужно что-то включить в BotFather?

Comment: Странно, протестировал у себя  и та же ошибка, что и у Вас. Обновил свой ответ и исправил баг, проверил - всё работает :)

Comment: Всё сработало, искал как раз, как работать с аргументом ContentType.ANY.    Сегодня его не сразу заметил, что ещё код добавился.   Благодадю Вас добрый человек.